# Is array-like object a datatype

Tags: javascript

as I found some inconsistencies in the materials I am wandering if the Array-like objects (i.e. arguments array) is or is not a JavaScript data type? Cause normally we speak about data types as follows: String, Number, Boolean, Array, Object, Null, Undefined. But array-like objects are predefined as well I suppose, so I don't know why they are not included.

Comment: Is your question answered? There are many answers already. If you believe one of them has solved your question, click the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An "array-like object" is any object that has numerical indices and a `length` property indicating how many values it contains.

"Array-like object" is not a datatype, but simply a category for certain objects that fit that description. For example, the following is an array-like object, and it derives directly from `Object`, not anything more specific:

```
var alo = {
    0: "hello",
    1: 3,
    length: 2
};
```

You can often use certain array operations on array-like objects and they will still work as though they were arrays. In particular, you can use the `slice()` method to convert an array-like object into an actual array:

```
var a = Array.prototype.slice.call(alo); // a is an actual array with the values
                                         // "hello" and 3
```

and you can use certain array methods directly on array-like objects without first converting them to arrays. The following prints out "hello" and "3":

Array.prototype.forEach.call(alo, function (v) { console.log(v); })

Comment: "You can often use certain array options" - actually, always. Array methods are generic and only require their `this` argument to have `length`.

Comment: @georg It would seem that's not entirely the case. If you execute `Array.prototype.concat.call(alo, [1, 2, 3])`, you will get `[alo, 1, 2, 3]` and not `["hello", 3, 1, 2, 3]`.

Answer (score 0):

No, array-like objects are called such because they are simply a Object, with integer keys. Example:

```
var myArraylike = {
    0: "someValue",
    1: "moreValues",
    "length": 2
};
myArraylike[0] == "someValue"; //true
```

They are not considered a datatype of its own, as you can notice by running:

```
typeof myArraylike; //returns "object"
```

Note that other "objects" are not a datatype of their own by themselves, because of the prototype concept:

```
typeof Array; //returns "function"
```

Constructors are no more than functions, and their product is a object:

```
typeof new Array(); //returns "object"
```

But how are those objects (instances of `Array`, `Date`, etc) considered their own type? The answer is the above mentioned "prototype" concept. Let's define our own "type"!

```
function CoolType() {
    this.y = 10;
}
CoolType.prototype.doCoolStuff = function() {
    console.log(this.y);
}
```

We created a function which refers `this`, a special keyword that resolves to the current object. We also defined a function called `doCoolStuff` in a special `prototype` property of `CoolType`.

When we instantiate `CoolType` (using `new`), its prototype is copied into the newly created object, and then the `CoolType` function body is executed:

```
var x = new CoolType();
x.doCoolStuff(); //prints 10
```

Any property which doesn't exist on the object will be retrieved from its prototype (which in turn will check its prototype, if it has no such property either). This way, you can inherit behavior from objects:

```
function AwesomeType() {
    this.y = 42;
}

AwesomeType.prototype = CoolType;

var x = new AwesomeType();
x.doCoolStuff(); //prints 42
```

You might wonder "what all of this has to do with array-like objects??", and the reason is: array-like objects are objects that behave like a array (have a length and numeric-keyed properties, as seen above), but whose prototype is not `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript type system is somewhat inconsistent.  What types exist kind of depends on how you ask.  The most basic way to get the type of a value is with the `typeof` operator:

```
typeof(2) // 'number'
typeof('foo') // 'string'
typeof(true) // 'boolean'
typeof(undefined) // 'undefined'
typeof(null) // 'object'
typeof([]) // 'object'
typeof({}) // 'object'
typeof((function(){return arguments;})()) // 'object'
```

As you can see the `typeof` operator considers `arguments` to be an object but then it also considers normal arrays to be objects, and for that matter null.  (Out of trivial interest, null is actually an object because of a mistake in the original implementation of the language that got locked into the spec early on).  There are other ways of telling what type a value has though.  A common technique is to use `Object.prototype.toString.call()`:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(2) // '[object Number]'
Object.prototype.toString.call('foo') // '[object String]'
Object.prototype.toString.call(true) // '[object Boolean]'
Object.prototype.toString.call(undefined) // '[object Undefined]'
Object.prototype.toString.call(null) // '[object Null]'
Object.prototype.toString.call([]) // '[object Array]'
Object.prototype.toString.call({}) // '[object Object]'
Object.prototype.toString.call((function(){return arguments;})()) // '[object Arguments]'
```

As you can see this method is much more effective.  It does have limitations though.  Specifically user defined classes:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(new (function Foo(){})()) // '[object Object]'
```

The best way to find the name of an object's class is `.constructor`:

```
(2).constructor.name // 'Number'
('foo').constructor.name // 'String'
(true).constructor.name // 'Boolean'
(undefined).constructor.name // TypeError
(null).constructor.name // TypeError
([]).constructor.name // 'Array'
({}).constructor.name // 'Object'
((function(){return arguments;})()).constructor.name // 'Object'
(new (function Foo(){})()).constructor.name // 'Foo'
```

As you can see however this doesn't work for arguments, null, or undefined.  It may be of interest that the Chrome console uses `constructor.name` when it displays values with a user defined class:

```
// (Chrome only)

>   ({a: 1})
<-  Object {a: 1}

>   new (function Foo(){this.a = 1;})()
<-  Foo {a: 1}

>   ({constructor: {name: 'Bar'}})
<-  Bar {constructor: Object}
```

In practice I tend to use the type methods defined in underscore for most of my type checking.

Arguments also differ from arrays in a number of practical ways.  Specifically, while the length property of an array gets updated if it is modified, arguments don't, also methods that are built in on arrays are not built in on arguments:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].slice(2,4) // [3, 4]
x = (function(){return arguments})(1,2,3,4,5)
x.slice(2, 4) // TypeError
```

There is a workaround though:

```
[].slice.call(x, 2, 4) // [3, 4]
```

(the above was tested in Node.js, Chrome, and Firefox)
(internet explorer notably deviates from this)

Answer (score -3):

An array is a object to store datatypes and other objects.